# createECDH of crypto module in electron 4+ doesn't support secp256k1

Tags: node.js, electron, cryptojs, ecdh

My project used electron 3.1.13, and the code below is running well.

```
class MessageEncryption {
    private ec = crypto.createECDH('secp256k1');
    private key = this.ec.generateKeys();
    private shared;

    getPublicKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    setSharedKey(key) {
        this.shared = this.ec.computeSecret(key);
    }
}
```

However when I upgrade the version of electron to 4.0.0+, here comes an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to create EC_KEY using curve name
```

So I run the `crypto.getCurves()`, and the result shows below.

```
Array(4)
  0: "prime256v1"
  1: "secp224r1"
  2: "secp384r1"
  3: "secp521r1"
```

'secp256k1' is not in the list. :(

I want to use both high version of electron and 'secp256k1', is there a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: im having the same issue using Electron 16.0.0 nightly. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Hey, we also experience the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If `crypto` module doesn't have what you need, just use another one. There's a lot of encryption related modules on NPM.

Try out a few encryption modules to figure out if they have `secp256k1`:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=crypt

Or just search for `secp256k1` directly:

https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=secp256k1